# How to split a string made of datas with "|" as separator in R

Tags: r

I am currently working on a project for which I need to use data from this website : https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/degree_days/weighted/daily_data/1999/StatesCONUS.Heating.txt

Those are the heating degree days in the US for a year. I need the data and to make it a bit more "exploitable" than it is in this .txt format.

Thus, my goal is to retrieve the data, only from Kansas (KS) for each year, then to get all the HDDs (Heating Degree Days), but separately, in a vector, which is not the case yet. My
roblem is that I have tried to split the single string that I get for KS, but when I use str_split(uncleaned_data, pattern= "|"), it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

lien="https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/degree_days/weighted/daily_data/"
annees <- c("2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021","2022","2023")

data_KS <- read_delim("https://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/degree_days/weighted/daily_data/1999/StatesCONUS.Heating.txt", delim="|",col_names=FALSE)
HDD_data<- data_KS[18,]

# Data retrieval in HDD_data

for(i in 1:length(annees))
{lien_ <- paste(lien,annees[i],"StatesCONUS.Heating.txt",sep="/")
data_annee <- read_delim(lien_,delim="|",col_names=FALSE)
data_KS <- data_annee[18,]
HDD_data<-c(HDD_data,data_KS)}

# Formatting the data : getting all the degree days in a vector cl_data

unclean_data<-HDD_data$X1[[1]]
unclean_data<-str_replace_all(unclean_data,"|"," ")
cl_data<- str_split(unclean_data[1], pattern=" ")
```

I have the impression R does not recognize the "|" as a separator, thus splits my string of data a bit too much.

I have also tried without replacing the "|" by " " and it does not work. It appears that there is a problem with the different dataframes but I can't figure it out.

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me find a way to retrieve the HDDs from the different years in a nice table, with years as columns and HDDs as rows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 lines at the beginning of the file are messing with your read in

Change this:

```
data_KS <- read_delim(..., delim="|",col_names=FALSE)
```

To this:

```
data_KS <- read_delim(..., delim="|",col_names=FALSE,skip=3)
```

The `skip=3` will get you where you want